# Is the beach below the cliff on main street accessible?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* is it possible to get to the beach below the cliff on Main Street if I build a bridge on the beach in the residential area?

[image: Main Street Beach (from animalcrossing.wikia.com)]

Comment: Are you even *allowed* to build a bridge there? I didn't try there when I built my first bridge today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just got a wet suit tonight and attempted swimming to the "Main Street" area.  There was a section of beach in my village that was previously inaccessible because I could not build a bridge there, but I was able to swim to it. Unfortunately, the beach ends abruptly with a cliff blocking access past the railroad bridge.

[image]

There are also very conspicuous boulders in the ocean blocking access towards Main Street, so it seems this is impossible (by design) by means of diving/swimming.

Answer (score 3):

I finished my first bridge public works project last night, so I decided to try and see if I could build my second one on the beach in the residential area.

However, as soon as you go to the top of the ramp to the beach and try to walk down, Isabelle stops you, saying "What's the matter, Mayor? Let's finish our work first!" She also says this if you attempt to head to Main Street, the Train Station, or other areas.

In addition, there's nothing mentioned in the [Main Street article on Nookipedia](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Main_Street) that mentions any of the upgrades/new stores letting you have beach access. 
Given that there's no way to get down to the beach from Main Street, you're blocked from building a bridge from your own beach, I don't believe there's a way to access this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can go there but it isn't a beach, just the sea. You can use the net glitch to dive in though, which is quite fun.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I still want to answer it in case anyone is still wondering about that beach.
You only can get there using a glitch (I used the net glitch).
On your map it seems like a beach, but it actually is just the sea.

Here is a picture of it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The beach and sand IS in fact there, but you cannot see it without hacking the game. I found a very little blot of sand, then the game crashed.
It's behind the boulders.